# Facebook Page Image returning null in FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I am attempting to retrieve the image from a facebook page. I have retrieved the page ID, and now I need to use this ID to get the image from the page. I am using the following code:

```
let pictureRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: picPath, parameters: ["fields" : "data"], HTTPMethod: "GET")
                            pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result, error) -> Void in
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    print("picResult: \(result)")
                                } else {
                                    print(error!)
                                }
                            })
```

I am not getting an error, but my result is null. The picpath looks like this:

```
/110475388978628/picture
```

I copied the code directly from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/picture/) but it isn't working. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong? I have the access token because I am able to get the page ID through the graph request

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the picture in the same request as the rest of the users information you can do it all in one graph request.

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"])
request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
    let info = result as! NSDictionary
    if let imageURL = info.valueForKey("picture")?.valueForKey("data")?.valueForKey("url") as? String {
        //Download image from imageURL
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no parameter called "fields". replace ["fields" : "data"] with nil

```
let pictureRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: picPath, parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
                            pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result, error) -> Void in
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    print("picResult: \(result)")
                                } else {
                                    print(error!)
                                }
                            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Graph API explorer tool to help construct the graph request first: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

In this case, you'll see that you want the graph path to be just the object id (i.e., your `picPath` should be just `110475388978628` and your parameters should be `[ "fields" : "picture"]`.

Then you'll want to parse the "url" out of the `result["picture"]["data"]["url"]`.